# C# after form loading element auto load problem

Tags: c#, windows

In windows application, I want to show for example my pc name when I use  toolStripStatusLabel and code like:

```
    private void toolStripStatusLabel2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string CurrentMachineName = Environment.MachineName;
        toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = CurrentMachineName;

    }
```

after I just build this application [show that type not show pc name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiH3a.png)

but if I click to pc name that time show my pc name
[after click show pc name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uj137.png)

**but I need to show when my from load after auto load my pc name**

I am using C# with windows application.

Comment: You mean you want PC name to be displayed in this label on form load? So why you are setting it on Click event?

Comment: I am new learning  C# with windows application please tell me how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move you code to `form_Load` event instead of `label_Click` , e.g.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = Environment.MachineName;
}
```

as it is obvious from `_Click` name - this event will be fired after specific control would be clicked

And `_Load` - on control initialization